# cannot share a folder with docker container

Tags: docker, docker-machine, boot2docker

I am running a python interactive docker container on Ubuntu 14.04 using docker 17.03.1. I want to share files between local host and docker container so that files I create in the container are visible in the local directory and vice-versa. However when I run the following command I see an empty working directory in the container with no files.

```
docker run -e USER=$USER -e USERID=$UID -v /home/watts/python:/home/watts/python -w=/home/watts/python -p 8888:8888 --rm -it watts/python jupyter notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir=/home/watts/python --allow-root
```

Comment: is dir /home/watts/python in host exists and consists of file? if no then docker removes contents from container working dir. try inserting some files in either of location

Comment: yes. /home/watts/python exists on the local host and is non empty. It contains both files and subfolders. I want to see all contents in the container.

Comment: It will be help full if you could provide more details as we cannot run the command. When I try it says `docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for watts/python, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.`

Comment: then watts/python image is in private repo, does above image belongs to your repo? if yes then do docker login and provide username & password.
its just like private git repo in order to access u need to login first

Comment: @J.Ordaz you can try pulling any public interactive docker image on linux. Eg. kaggle/python. Or try any public image with rstudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just run this command:

```
docker run -v `pwd`/home/watts/python:/home/watts/python -it kaggle/python /bin/bash
```

And after that, I started creating a few files both host and container. All files are visible in both sides.

Hopefully this will help.